# Get-AzureStorageBlob throws Can not find your azure storage credential

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have just started using Azure and I am facing issues using the PowerShell cmdlets to work with my storage account.

I have created a Storage account and a container in that storage account. Next I installed the Azure Powershell SDK and command lets etc. and imported the publishsettings file. When I do the Get-AzureSubscription or Get-AzureStorageAccount command it correctly shows my subscription in the PowerShell console along with various storage end points.

However if I do a Get-AzureStorageBlob call or a Set-AzureStorageBlobContent I get the following error

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob : Can not find your azure storage credential. Please set current storage account using
"Set-AzureSubscription" or set the "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING" environment variable.
```

I am literally at wits ends here. A Google search on this error string only brings up references to code on Github etc. Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right so I finally managed to do this! Here is the overall details on how to use PowerShell to create a blob in Azure and store a file there.

http://www.nikgupta.net/2013/09/azure-blob-storage-powershell/

> ```
> $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName FunkyStorage -StorageAccountKey {Enter your storage account key here}
>
> Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob "MyFunkyBlob" -Container FunkyContainer-File "c:\temp\1.txt" -Context $context -Force
> ```

Comment: When I try this I'm getting the following.  Any idea how to avoid?  
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Model.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContext" value of type 
"Deserialized.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Model.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContext" to type 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Model.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContext".

Comment: A quick search on the internet points this to either an access related or network related issue. Does this help http://robertsmit.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/microsoft-azure-file-server-system-error64-or-new-azurestorageshare-cannot-bind-parameter-context-azure-cloud-mvpbuzz/

Comment: Use `$localStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -Local` to deal with your local dev storage.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to set the 'current' subscription to use. For that, you must run `Select-AzureSubscription`.

If you run `Get-AzureSubscription`, you'll see all subscriptions in your publish settings. One of those subscriptions should be set as the default. As you scroll through the result list, you'll see one property, `IsDefault` for each subscription, set to `True` or `False`. If the subscription you're using is set to `False`, run:

`Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName mysub`

Hopefully that fixes the issue you're running into.

Comment: Thanks David. I tried that too but no luck. I actually eventually found the way to do this. Shall blog about it and post link here to help others soon!

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick FYI: you can do this another (and faster way).  I build a web language atop Windows PowerShell that heavily integrates with Azure.  It's called [PowerShell Pipeworks](http://powershellpipeworks.com).

You can use 4 cmdlets to interact with the blobs:

- Get-Blob
- Import-Blob
- Export-Blob
- Remove-Blob

All take a -StorageAccount and a -StorageKey, and also a -StorageAccountSetting and a -StorageKeySetting.  You can save creds to disk (or for use in a web app by using Add-SecureSetting).  Once any blob cmdlet has a storage account, it will continue to reuse it.

Export-Blob is also handy in that you can pipe in a directory to it, and it will create the right content types, and provide -Public, which will mark the container it's stored in as public.

These cmdlets are a notch older (~3 months) than the Azure ones, and still about 3/4ths the time to execute (I believe a major chunk of this is their slower lookup on credentials), and are worth a try.

Comment: Thanks. Can you leave this as a comment on the blog so I can modify my post too and incorporate your links there?