# Upload Images to Azure Storage Using Portal (not programmatically)

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-blob-storage

I need a SQL Server database that stores images, and their name, category, etc, so the SQL table will have 5 or so columns. I'm using Azure as my SQL Server host. It appears I cannot seem to insert image data into my `VARBINARY(MAX)` column from SQL Server Management Studio which was my first plan. I cannot do this because I cannot seem to give my user permissions to use `BULK LOAD`. Azure SQL seems to make this impossible. I think I need to use Azure Storage, and then in the SQL Server database, just store a link to the image.

To be clear, I want the images in the database already, I do not want to add them from within the application I am developing. The application I'm developing will only download the images to the device, not upload them.

So How do I upload the images to Azure Storage using the portal, not using code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So how do I upload the images to Azure Storage using the portal, not using code?

## Short Answer

**You cannot.** The portal does not have a way to upload an image to a storage container from either the old or the new portal.

## Alternative

Use the AzCopy Command-Line Utility by Microsoft. It allows you to do what you want with just two command lines. There is [terrific tutorial here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/).

First, [download and install the utility](http://aka.ms/downloadazcopy). Second, open a command prompt and navigate to the installation AzCopy install directory. Third, upload a file to your storage account. Here are the second and third steps.

```
> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy

> AzCopy /Source:folder /Dest:account /DestKey:key /Pattern:file
```

And here are what the parameters mean.

- `Source` The folder on your computer that contains the images to upload.
- `Dest` The address of the storage container at which to store the images.
- `DestKey` The primary access key for your storage account.
- `Pattern` The name of the file to upload (or a pattern).

## Example

This uploads an image named `my-cat.png` from the `C:\temp` folder on my computer to a storage contained called `mvp1`. If you wanted to upload all the `png` images in that folder, you could replace `my-cat.png` with `*.png` and it work upload them all.

```
AzCopy /Source:C:\temp /Dest:https://my.blob.core.windows.net/mvp1 /DestKey:tLlbC59ggDdJ+Dg== /Pattern:my-cat.png
```

You might also what to take a look at the answers to this question: [How do I upload some file into Azure blob storage without writing my own program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584036/how-do-i-upload-some-file-into-azure-blob-storage-without-writing-my-own-program)

Comment: Really good detailed answer. AzCopy would be an easy way to do this. I went with the free version of [CloudBerry Explorer for Azure Blob Storage](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/download-thanks.aspx?prod=cbazure) as per the answer in your link at the bottom of your answer (It was the answerers personal favourite). I must say, I used it instantly without needing any tutorial. It has an easy to understand GUI. By the way, I can only view the top 25 images in my container in the Azure portal. Do you know why? Also, is a container for categorising your storage? I have them all in 1 container.

Comment: Yo. It might be that the Azure portal has pagination. Is there a way to click to view the next page. A container could be for categorizing storage. Every blob must be in a container. There is a write up on containers here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Comment: Haha yes, the page numbers were covered by an alert to try the new Azure Portal. Thanks!