# How to write a stored procedure that use a temp table created from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application developped in C# that follows this worflow:

- Read CSV files
- Create a temp table
- Send the CSV data to the temp table with SqlBulkCopy
- Call a stored procedure to MERGE the temp table in the real table
- Delete the temp table

  ```
  using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
  {
      dbConnection.Open();

      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [#UpdatedData]([Path] [nvarchar](50))", dbConnection))
      {
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

      using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
      {
          bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[#UpdatedData]";

          bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
      }

      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_MergeData", dbConnection))
      {
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("DROP TABLE [#UpdatedData]", dbConnection))
      {
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
  }
  ```

My problem is I'm creating the temp table in C#, and I can't write the SQL Server stored procedure because it doesn't find the temp table. Is there any workaround?

I'm using localdb for dev and SQL Azure for production.

Comment: sqlserver also have temp table concept. Just google it..

Comment: you can use OPENROWSET...

Comment: Why not just create a table and then simply truncate it when you are done.  Sometimes the simple solution is the best.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain why you need to use a temp table. The logic you described is very common in the ETL area, but there's no need to use a temp table, just use a permanent one.

Comment: @MarkKram could you please give an example, I'm interested in your solution! thanks

Comment: @Pondlife I have to merge big CSV files in my database and EF cannot handle it, so I'm looking to do it with SQL Server directly

Comment: SQL Azure [supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621784.aspx) bcp and SSIS, so those could both be options for what you want to do. And it's always best to describe your real problem rather than your solution. In this case, a better question would be "How can I load large .csv files into SQL Azure?" See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352660/bulk-load-files-into-sql-azure).

Comment: Just create a table before hand and then execute a TRUNCATE TABLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it without permanent table or global table!

Instead of trying to create a MERGE stored procedure in SQL Server, I wrote a big MERGE function in a string in C# and execute it as normal SQL Query!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global temp table:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "CREATE TABLE [##UpdatedData]([Path] [nvarchar](50))"
    , dbConnection))
```

[Prefix local temporary table names with single number sign (#table_name), and prefix global temporary table names with a double number sign (##table_name).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

---

**Edit**

As you cannot have global temp tables in SQL Azure you'll probably have to create a real table.

Comment: Unfortunately global temp tables are not available in SQL Azure. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Swell oh well (you learn something new every day) ... I guess you'll have to go with a permanent table