# How to bulk insert into Azure SQL database without Bulk Copy Program (BCP)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

I want to bulk insert .csv files of sizes no greater than 50MB in an Azure SQL database in possibly no more than 10 minutes or so.

However, bulk insert is [not available](https://thecodegarden.net/bulk-insert-azure-sql/) for the cloud. As pointed out in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352660/bulk-load-files-into-sql-azure), BCP is a viable solution but it requires to bulk insert the data in a local database. However, this is not an option in a PaaS infrastructure where there is no control at operative system level and it's not possible to create and manage a database.

At the moment, a .csv of 131KB requires more than 10 minutes to be uploaded raw by raw using a Standard S3: 100 DTU, 250 GB Azure SQL Database. How to speed up the upload of at least one order of magnitude?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
table = pd.Dataframe(<your_data_here>)
sql_driver = <driver>
sql_server = <server>
sql_user = <user>
sql_pass = <password>
sql_db = <database_name>
sql_conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://'+sql_user+':'+sql_pass+'@'+sql_server+'/'+sql_db+'?driver='+sql_driver)
table.to_sql('table_name', con=sql_conn)
```

Comment: Also consider Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bulk insert from BLOB storage account using below syntax:

```
BULK INSERT Test
FROM 'source/data/Test.csv'
WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
              FORMAT='CSV', CODEPAGE = 65001, 
              FIRSTROW=2,
              TABLOCK);
```

For more information, please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-2017) documentation.

Comment: Can you please share more info about Bulk Insert

Comment: @Narendra https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/02/23/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database/

Comment: @Narendrahttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-2017